# C# Dice roller cannot perform with specific number

Tags: c#, constructor

I have tried to run the following code to make a dice roller which it can return the correct current value of the face of dice with specific number of faces, such that if I input number of face that is less than 3, the constructor will return the default value of faces  and the default number of faces. Otherwise, the dice will roll according to the given number. However, when I try to input number that is less than 3, the number of faces won't return the default value at all. What should I do to fix it?

```
public class Die
{
    // Implement your 'Die' class here
    private int numFaces; 
    private int faceValue;
    Random rand = new Random();



    // Default Constructor
    public Die()
    {
        numFaces = 6;
        faceValue = 1;


    }

    // Random Constructor
    public Die(int faces)
    {

        if (faces >=3)
        {
            numFaces = faces;
            RollDie();
            GetNumFaces();
            faceValue = GetFaceValue();
        }

        else
        {
            numFaces = 6;
            faceValue = 1;
        }



    }



    // Rolls the die
    public void RollDie()
    {

        faceValue = rand.Next(numFaces) + 1;

    }


    // Get the vlaue of current face
    public int GetFaceValue()
    {

        return faceValue;
    }

    // Get the number of face
    public int GetNumFaces()
    {

        return numFaces;
    }
}

// end Class Die


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        Die myDie = new Die(10);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: 'the number of faces won't return the default value at all', So what does it return then ?

Comment: Here is a hint: *please* don't call RollDie() in the constructor. The constructor is supposed to initialize the object. The way you have written the class now you should probably name it `DieRoll` and make the method `RollDie` `private`. Instead of `GetFaceValue()` just let `RollDie` return an `int` and use that to generate die rolls. Clearly this is homework, so maybe you are asked to set up the class in this specific way, but hopefully you'll be able to change this.

Comment: You should make the instance of `Random` `static` so that you avoid bugs when you use two or more dice.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
public class Die
{
    private System.Random rand;
    private int faceValue, numFaces;

    public int GetFaceValue()
    {
        return faceValue;
    }

    public int GetNumFaces()
    {
        return numFaces;
    }

    public void Roll()
    {
        faceValue = rand.Next(1, numFaces + 1);
    }

    public Die()
    {
        rand = new System.Random();
        faceValue = 1;
        numFaces = 6;
    }

    public Die(int faces) : this()
    {
        if (faces >= 3) numFaces = faces;
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Die d1 = new Die(10);
        Die d2 = new Die(2);
        System.Console.WriteLine("D1: {0} faces; value: {1}",
                                 d1.GetNumFaces(),
                                 d1.GetFaceValue());
        System.Console.WriteLine("D2: {0} faces; value: {1}",
                                 d2.GetNumFaces(),
                                 d2.GetFaceValue());
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I guess you are working on this (https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/using-c-code-read-instructions-carefully-also-system-handle-faces-minimum-use-sample-code--q27544582); as it does not ask for rolling the die when it is initialized, I edited my code to reflect that.